# How to compare even indexes using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to solve this problem :

numbers with the even indexes are sorted in descending order, and the numbers with the odd indexes are sorted in ascending order."

Here is my code:

```
def Sorted(lst):
    if not lst:
        return not lst
    
    if lst[0]>lst[2] and lst[1]>lst[3]:
        
        return Sorted(lst[:-1])



def main():
    n=int(input("enter length of the list: "))
    lst=[]
    print("enter places of the list:")
    for i in range (n):
        lst.append(int(input()))
    
    print(Sorted(lst))    
    
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to move ahead in steps of two, not to switch even/odd indeces. That will affect your base case. Also, you will have to do some checks on the length of the list not run into index errors:

```
def is_sorted(lst):
    if len(lst) < 3:
        return True
    if lst[0] < lst[2]:
        return False
    if len(lst) > 3 and lst[1] > lst[3]:
        return False
    return is_sorted(lst[2:])
```